# Application loader Unable to extract entitlements from application

Tags: ios, ipa

I had a IPA which generate by a plugin for discuz forum, the ipa was signed with enterprise developers certificate, I want to resign with my developers certificate & submit to apple by application loader

I use iresign to resign the ipa then send to apple by application loader, but it appear

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

Unable to extract entitlements from application: /var/folders/cv/pksp8dfs71x74zt9st8y01xm0000gn/T/AppByMe32484-resigned.zip/Payload/Donkey.app/Donkey
```

How ever I was sign the app with iPhone Distribution: my name as well as a mobile provision profile create

can't figure out what happen.. :( Please help Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible, I think you could do it like this.

First extract some likely entitlements from the App Store provisioning profile. This may need further editing.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "print :Entitlements " /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i AppStore.mobileprovision) > entitlements.plist
```

Then resign the binary using the

```
codesign -f -s YourDistributionSigningIdentity --entitlements entitlements.plist --resource-rules your.app/ResourceRules.plist your.app
```

And package it as an IPA

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v -o `pwd`/out.ipa your.app
```

If the app wasn't code signed, then your ResourceRules.plist may be missing. These are generic, just copy something [like this](https://gist.github.com/rfistman/7611401) into place.