# keep old app versions submitted to store and install them on dev iPhone

Tags: ios, ipa

I would like to keep versions submitted to the store to install them on my developer phone at a later time, is that possible? If I take that .ipa, how can I install it on my phone? Do I have another format than .ipa?

How can I build an archive of all my app store versions to install them at a later time?

I tried the solution from `Rhythmic Solution`, doesn't work yet ("A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."). My steps:

1. from the archives in Xcode, export one entry as App Store build
2. open iReSign
3. enter path to exported .ipa in first field
4. enter path to downloaded developer provisioning profile in second field
5. use an entitlements.plist created like [here](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/%20here)
6. select developer certificate
7. resign button
8. drag it on to the "installed apps" section in Xcode/devices
9. now I get the error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can upload all those versions on diawi.com and get the url and save them whenever you need that version just take the respective url and install in your phone.
On other note git is a very important tool to track the versions of you code.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I came across some ancient Ad Hoc builds of mine and wanted to try them out, but the technique works with AppStore submission builds, as well as developer and enterprise.

The general method is to
   1. unzip your .ipa file into an .app
   2. replace the `embedded.mobileprovision` provisioning profile (which has probably expired or does not allow installation on your device)
   3. the above step invalidates the app's signature, so you resign it
   4. zip the app back into an .ipa file
   5. install the app via over-the-air download, drag onto the Xcode Devices window or  itunes syncing (if you like pain)

[iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) can do steps 1-4 for you.

If you want to duplicate entitlements, you can [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159265/22147) - however that can be more complicated than simply copying them across, e.g. push notifications can change from production to development and vice versa.

Comment: looks promising! I just tried with developer provisioning profile and did not fill out the entitlement-thing... it didn't work unfortunately. Do I need to provide the entitlement.plist? If yes, where to take from?

Comment: I always get "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Comment: I added some info on entitlements. Not sure about your error, maybe add the steps you're taking into your question.

Comment: Have you made sure that the UDID of the device you're installing onto is in your provisioning profile? Also, I'm not sure how much iResign does - e.g. it may not make the bundleID of the app match the provisioning profile, so you'll have to check that.

Comment: yes, I did - my UDID is in the provisioning profile for sure. It doesn't work if I leave the bundle id to "unchanged" or set it explicitly...

Comment: Can you provide a link to an ipa?

Comment: The provisioning profile in that app has no provisioned device UDIDs - it's an appstore profile. Try and ad hoc/dev/enterprise profile instead?

Comment: okay, but that would mean that I always have to make two different builds when releasing an app, right? That I can't use the app store build? That would be a pitty as those apps are not exactly the same due to preprocessor macros etc.

Comment: you don't have to recompile, just replace the provisioning profile and re-sign  as per my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95895/discussion-between-rhythmic-fistman-and-swalkner).